# AEM 6.5: Editable templates > Any changes to templates are not getting applied post deployment

Tags: aem

We are currently pushing the editable templates via code base for test environments. The path to template root folder i.e. /conf/xyz is added as below:

```
<filter root="/conf/xyz" mode="merge"/>
```

If we do any changes to structure of template or anything else and push via code repo deployment, the changes do not reflect. However, if we delete the template from AEM and then push via deployment; the changes are reflecting.

I understand that editable templates are dynamic and should be created on the env directly instead of deploying via code repo but we need this functionality for now.

Kindly suggest

Comment: It works fine if I change the mode to update, but I would like to understand what should be added as per best practice and that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

About the different modes:

replace : This is the normal behavior. Existing content is replaced completely by the imported content, i.e. is overridden or deleted accordingly.

merge : Existing content is not modified, i.e. only new content is added and none is deleted or modified.

update : Existing content is updated, new content is added and none is deleted.

So that means update is your friend here as long as there are not changes done in AEM. Because update will overwrite existing nodes if the content is not the same.

We usually do the following to make sure that we don't break too much:

- package /conf/xyz from the author environment
- extract it into our repository (separate branch)
- merge dev changes and branch with extracted stuff
- build and deploy

Merging back changes from the author instance into the repo regularly will also help to reduce the number of possible conflicts.